# Is it possible to link multiple nodes to a single node?

Tags: java, pointers, tree

I'm trying to make a tree structure based on the linked list. Since linked list can only directly point to the next node(For singly linked list), I would like to modify the concept of the linked list. Is it possible to point at the one node from multiple nodes?

Here is an image in drawing

[image]

Comment: java does not have pointers

Comment: hmm I guess I should use a different method instead of pointing at one point

Comment: Are you talking about inventing a *tree*?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following would work:

```
class Node {
    Node sibling;
    Node child;
    Object item;
}
```

sibling will point to next Node at parallel level, child points to Node on lower level.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about this, but how do I point sibling node to the parent node in the coding? Since when I have multiple descendants. I tried to use List<Node<E>>, and make the inner node to be List<Node<E>> recursively until it reaches to the root or leafs. Btw, I'm using post-order input method for this one

Comment: This also makes it hard to remove nodes.

Answer (score 0):

See below my implementation:

```
package treeTest;

public class Node {
private Node left;
private Node right;
private String data;
public Node(String data) {
    this.data = data;
    left = null;
    right = null;
}

public Node getLeft() {
    return left;
}

public void setLeft(Node left) {
    this.left = left;
}

public Node getRight() {
    return right;
}

public void setRight(Node right) {
    this.right = right;
}

public String getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

}

```
package treeTest;

public class Tree {
private Node root;

public Tree() {
    root = null;
}

public void insert(String data) {
    root = insert(root, data);
}

private Node insert(Node node, String data) {
    if(node == null) {
        // Then create tree
        node = new Node(data);
    } else {
        if(data.compareTo(node.getData()) <= 0) {
            node.setLeft( insert(node.getLeft(), data));
        } else {
            node.setRight(insert(node.getRight(), data));
        }
    }
    return node;
}
```

}

```
package treeTest;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestTree {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Tree tree = new Tree();

    tree.insert("Hurricane");
    // Second level
    tree.insert("Cat1");
    tree.insert("Cat2");
    tree.insert("Cat3");
}

}
```

For more details checkout this [Java Program to Implement a Binary Search Tree using Linked Lists](http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-implement-binary-search-tree-using-linked-list/)

Comment: Ok, I got the concept but how does the binary tree node work for the parent that has three children?

Comment: By definition a binary tree is a tree data structure that has at most two children(or nodes). [Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree). But if you want to have a tree with 3 children you can just add another node and maybe name it middle

Comment: But what I'm constructing is to have the unlimited number of children. For example the user might want to have 10 children in one parent. So defining number of children node will not solve my problem so far. Thx for commenting back anyway.